# UIWebView global javascript variables not working

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I have embedded some html and js files in my iOS projects, to find next and previous occurrences of a text searched, The same works in browser and does not work in iOS, I have got the same code from the link below. AFter debugging i found out that my variables are not holding values between function call.

```
var currSelected = 0;

function jump(howHigh){


    prevSelected = currSelected;
    currSelected = currSelected + howHigh;
    alert("currSelected" + currSelected); //currSelected is always 1 
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TAxdp/

Please refer the above url to know what i am try to get done in UIWebView.

Please suggest for iOS in UIWebView to work.

Thanks 
djrecker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this to make variants global:

1)in js file

```
function test(){
    alert(i++);
}
```

2)in .m file

```
//call before function 'do'
- (void)makeVariantGlobal {  
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var i=0"];
}

//i++ works!
- (void)do {
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"test()"];
}
```